# How to integrate Disqus plugin for WordPress with JQuery Ajaxed content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, dynamic, disqus

I have implemented JQuery Ajax for dynamic content retrieval for my WordPress blog. But now I have a problem with DISQUS plugin, it just do not load anymore, because page is not reloading. For other small scripts I have used LiveQuery plugin for JQuery and it worked out well, but DISQUS is too complicated for me. Maybe someone could give me some directions where should I change DISQUS plugin files in order to make this work on dynamically generated page?

Answer (score 1):

The Disqus WordPress plugin is designed to load your comments when the page loads. It isn't designed to work with dynamic content like your site.

You can use [Disqus' Universal Code](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/) to reload the comments for the correct content on your site.